# How can I remove elements from plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, delete-row

Just a quick question: I want to remove plot elements. Such as col, main etc.

I am adding a picture to you can understand better.

https://hizliresim.com/XMQr0R

```
  str(nr)


  kmncluster <- kmeans(na.omit(nr), centers = 10, iter.max = 500, nstart = 5, algorithm="Lloyd")

  knr <- ndvi

  knr[] <- kmncluster$cluster

  values(knr) <- kmncluster$cluster

  mycolor <- c("#fef65b","#ff0000", "#daa520","#0000ff","#0000ff","#00ff00","#cbbeb5",
               "#c3ff5b", "#ff7373", "#00ff00", "#808080")

  par(mfrow = c(1,2))
  plot(ndvi, col = rev(terrain.colors(10)), main = 'Landsat-NDVI')
  plot(knr, main = 'Unsupervised classification', col = mycolor )


  dev.off()
```

I just want to keep the picture. I don't want to see any other information.

Comment: The picture in the link shows nothing useful.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I would like to remove ones marked red and I just want output picture (marked in green).

Comment: Sorry but there are no red or green anything. Are you sure you have posted the right picture or link?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I added a new photo for you, https://imgur.com/a/nKskj37 . I hope this will be more understandable. Thank you

Comment: I don't believe you can do that with R, try, for instance, ImageMagick.

Comment: @RuiBarradas This is output of my analysis and I want to show this output on my website. I connected html to R with rPlumber. I use OpenMap(OpenLayer) and GeoServer in my website and when I want to show this output of analysis on OpenMap, I have to remove elements from plot. So want this solution.  Thanks for your help. :)